# php regex changing split to preg_split - specific example

Tags: php, preg-split

Lots of questions similar but I have a specific example I would like some help with please.
Migrating older php 5.2 code to 5.3

```
for($s=0;$s<count($tmp=split("/",$check_for));$s++)
```

assumed would be

```
for($s=0;$s<count($tmp=preg_split("///",$check_for));$s++)
```

However, I get

```
Warning: preg_split() [function.preg-split]: Unknown modifier '/'
```

Can someone give me some direction please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first character of a `preg_XXX` pattern is the separator which separates the pattern from the options that follow. Therefore, you cannot use the separator in the pattern itself without escaping it.

Consider using a different separator, like `~`:

```
for($s=0;$s<count($tmp=preg_split("~/~",$check_for));$s++)
```